# xfce4: how to override Debian wallpaper?

Tags: debian, xfce, desktop, settings, wallpaper

After upgrade from Debian10 (buster) to Debian11 (bullseye = current testing) and rebooting, xfce4 shows a blueish wallpaper with a "debian^10" logo.

I should be able to override this choice from `Menu > Settings > Desktop > Background`, setting `Style` to `None`. However, this has no effect.

Comment: Now reported as a bug: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=939305.

Comment: The desktop background wallpaper or the login screen wallpaper?

Comment: Desktop for sure. Login screen I cannot tell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
xsetroot -solid midnightblue
```

(or whatever [xorg color](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X11_color_names)).

Answer (score 2):

A bit cumbersome, but you could use a different tool to handle your wallpaper, such as `feh`

```
feh --bg-scale /path/to/image
```

Hope this can help.

Comment: Not the clean solution I was hoping for, but a good workaround. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> I should be able to override this choice from Menu > Settings > Desktop > Background, setting Style to None. However, this has no effect.

Another option is setting the wallpaper via [`xfconf-query`](https://docs.xfce.org/xfce/xfconf/xfconf-query), (See: https://superuser.com/q/1327821/764283).

Comment: `$ xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop` yields `No property specified.` Now what?

Comment: Try running `xfconf-query -l` without `-c` to list all channels.

Comment: `xfconf-query -l` only lists "Channels: thunar-volman xsettings ... xfce4-desktop xfwm4". No parameter values.